# which is the correct way to declare charset in HTML page?

Tags: html, meta-tags

What is the difference between these meta tags in HTML

```
<meta name="http-equiv" content="Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in w3c validation first one is not recognized but for some reason I have to use that.

Comment: I recommend a combination of `<!doctype html>` and `<meta charset="utf-8">` instead. Those tags from your question belong in a museum.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `http-equiv` attribute allows to specify information that would normally be provided via HTTP headers (and user agents can opt to handle it as such) while using `name` is a syntax to set free-form arbitrary key/value pairs with additional information about the document (author, keywords...)

Here's the [spec for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4):

> **name** = name [CS]
>       This attribute identifies a property name. This specification does not list legal values for this attribute.
>   **http-equiv** = name [CI]
>       This attribute may be used in place of the name attribute. HTTP servers use this attribute to gather information for HTTP response
>   message headers.

Your first example is possibly legal but it won't render any appreciable result.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the first one before.

Here's the simplest:

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

If you're using XHTML, you can also declare the charset in the XML prologue:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

By the way, the first one is new for HTML5, but a lot of work has been done to demonstrate that it works on all known extant browsers, so it's safe to use, even with an older DOCTYPE.